# Powershell XAML - Use XAML datatemplate to create new tabitems

Tags: powershell, xaml, datatemplate, tabitem

I have a small XAML form and i run it from within a powerShell script. It has a controltemplate called "newTab" which I use to create a tab with two buttons. Inside the XAML that works fine.
But now I want to create a new tabItem inside the PowerShell code but missing the right syntax to achieve this. I was following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF)  tutorial with is unfortunately in C#. The author did the trick like this:

```
// create new tab item
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
tab.Header = string.Format("Tab {0}", count);
tab.Name = string.Format("tab{0}", count);
tab.HeaderTemplate = tabDynamic.FindResource("TabHeader") as DataTemplate;
```

---

PowerShell script:

```
[xml]$XAML = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" MinWidth="250">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="newTab" TargetType="TabItem"  >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Button Content="Test1"/>
                <Button Content="Test2"/>            
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TabControl Name="tabCon" TabStripPlacement="left" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <TabItem Template="{StaticResource newTab}"/>  
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader"; exit}

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

#$myNewTab =  New-Object PSObject -Property "NewTab"    
#$tab = new-Object System.Windows.Controls.TabItem -Style "{StaticResource newTab}"
#$tabCon.AddChild($xaml.tryFindResource("newTab"))

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FindResource` in PowerShell the same way you would in C#:

```
# Create new tab item
$tab = [System.Windows.Controls.TabItem]::new()

# Set template embedded in XAML form
$tab.Template = $Form.FindResource('newTab')
```

Comment: Great, works fine. Thanks for the fast help!