# Generating/ connecting WPF tabitems dynamically in powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell

Not sure what the best way to word the question is, but how can I dynamically generate all these elements and assign an add_click on and to the generated elements?

I am using a foreach loop in powershell to build a tabbed WPF window based of the contents of a powershell object.

Everything works up until adding the control to the tabbutton to allow it to display the tabitem. I assume it is because in the foreach I am using the same variable name for each element, and I am not sure how to specify which tabitem is assigned to each tabbutton.

Additionally, I am looking for a powershell only solution.

I thought I might be able to use `New-Variable`/`Get-Variable` to build the variables with the counter included in the variable name but the `add_click` still could not call the tabitem.

---

**Added 20 Jan 2023**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing

#Region XAML for base gui
$Xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="1000"
    Height="700"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    Background="#35333a"
    BorderBrush="#666374"
    Foreground="#514e5d"

    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="CanResize">

  <Grid Background="#241b2f" Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="20" Background="white" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Name="CloseButton" />

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4">
      <StackPanel Name="QuestionTabsPanel">
      </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <TabControl Background="#241b2f" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Padding="-1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="TabControlPanel" SelectedIndex="0">
    </TabControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
"@
#EndRegion

# get questions from json and convert them to objects
$Json = get-content 'C:\Users\d.eckhout.mil\Desktop\Files\questions.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
$Questions = $Json | foreach{
  [pscustomobject]@{
      QuestionText = $_.questiontext
      Image = $_.image
      Answers = $_.answers
      CorrectAnswer = $_.correctanswer
      Explaination = $_.explaination
      }
}

# counting variables
$QuestionsCorrect = 0
$QuestionNumber = 1

# randomize questions
$Questions = $Questions | Sort-Object {Get-Random}

# build window with base xaml
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($Xaml)
[xml]$xml = $Xaml
$xml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name) }

# custom close button event
$CloseButton.Add_Click({$Window.Close()})

# Make window moveable
$Window.Add_MouseDown({
     if ($_.ChangedButton -eq 'Left'){
                $this.DragMove()
     }
})

# loop through our question objects and build a tab for each
foreach ($Question in $Questions){
  #Region Add a tab button for the question to sidebar
  $TabButton = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Button
  $TabButton.Name = "TabButton$QuestionNumber"
  $TabButton.content = "$QuestionNumber"
  $TabButton.Height="40"
  $TabButton.Background="#241b2f"
  $TabButton.BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
  $TabButton.Foreground="#ffffff"

  $QuestionTabsPanel.Children.Add($TabButton)
  #EndRegion

  #Region Create tab content panel for the question
  $TabContent = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.TabItem
  #$TabContent.Visibility="Collapsed"
  $TabContent.Name="TabContent$QuestionNumber"
  $TabControlPanel.Items.Add($TabContent)
  #EndRegion

  $TabButton.Add_Click({
   $sauceButton=$_ #the button this click event was triggered by
   $sauceButtonContent=[Int]$sauceButton.Content #its content casted as Int
   $tabIndexToSelect=$sauceButtonContent-1 # the first tabItem has index 0
   $TabControlPanel.SelectedIndex = $tabIndexToSelect
})

  #Region Add grid to tab content area...grid lets us better control placement of children
  $TabContentStack = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel
  $TabContentStack.Name="TabStack$QuestionNumber"
  $TabContent.Content = ($TabContentStack)
  #EndRegion

  #Region Add question text to grid
  $TabContentQuestionText = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
  $TabContentQuestionText.HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  $TabContentQuestionText.VerticalAlignment="Top"
  $TabContentQuestionText.TextWrapping="Wrap"
  $TabContentQuestionText.Text=$Question.QuestionText
  $TabContentQuestionText.FontSize="14"
  $TabContentQuestionText.Height="21"
  $TabContentQuestionText.Foreground="#ffffff"
  $TabContentStack.Children.Add($TabContentQuestionText)
  #EndRegion

  $QuestionNumber++
}
$Window.ShowDialog()
```

```
[
{
  "questiontext": "lorem ipsum?",
  "answers": [
    "first ipsum",
    "second ipsum",
    "third ipsum",
    "fourth ipsum"
  ],
  "correctanswer": "lorem ipsum",
  "explaination": "lorem ipsum"
},
{
  "questiontext": "lorem ipsum?",
  "answers": [
    "first ipsum",
    "second ipsum",
    "third ipsum",
    "fourth ipsum"
  ],
  "correctanswer": "lorem ipsum",
  "explaination": "lorem ipsum"
}
]
```

[picture of gui running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D59C.png)

Comment: I was able to fix this issue by using the ".GetNewClosure()" method, which when tacked onto my foreach forces the variables to be applied as their values as opposed to being  a reference for the variable itself,

Answer (score 0):

You can use selecedIndex with the content of the button your click event originates from:

```
$TabButton.Add_Click({
   $sauceButton=$_ #the button this click event was triggered by
   $sauceButtonContent=[Int]$sauceButton.Content #its content casted as Int
   $tabIndexToSelect=$sauceButtonContent-1 # the first tabItem has index 0
   $TabControlPanel.SelectedIndex = $tabIndexToSelect 
})
```

However I recommend to create a datacontext, add ps-objects to that context for each tabitem and bind it to your tabcontrol, and set the  property itemsource to "binging" simular to this example: [Powershell XAML - Use XAML datatemplate to create new tabitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72184223/powershell-xaml-use-xaml-datatemplate-to-create-new-tabitems)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the slow reply. Couldnt play over the holidays. Ive updated the script above with your first solution. 

I think because Im using custom tabs there is an error, because the result looks like something is trying to use normal tabs instead of the tabs I made.

Not sure I understand the other solution you provided. Could you explain it another way?